# Is var str: String mutable or immutable?

Tags: android, string, kotlin, immutability

I have declared a String variable in Kotlin as like.

`var str: String`

The Kotlin document contradict for mutability concept.
As per document...
var is mutable.
[image: var is mutable]

But for String it define as immutable.
[image: String is immutable]

So please clarify contradiction...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, String *`variable`* is mutable, but  String *`Value`* is Immutable.

> Appreciate with @cricket_007

Let me Describe deeply what happened behind When you declare variable.

```
val string1 = "abcd"  
val string2 = "abcd"
```

[image]

As Shown above image and Declaration.

-String pool is a special storage area in **The Heap Memory**.

-When a `string is created` and if the string `already exists` in the pool, the reference of the `existing string will be returned`, instead of creating a new object and returning its reference.

-If string is not immutable, changing the string with one reference will lead to the wrong value for the other references.

-Now with above our example Value Assign to Variable **String1** now we can use this variable.

also we can change the value

```
string1.renameTo("Hi This Is Test")
```

So What happen at behind in memory ?
->yes,
**if**   *"Hi This Is Test"* this string available it will return a reference to "**string1**"
**else** it Create new space and give reference To "**string1**"

Actually, that's Why String called immutable.

**Reference - [Link](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/immutable/1032)**

Answer (score 8):

I don't like way the documentation is written either but there is no contradiction in reality. They are using the word *mutable* in a way that invites a comparison between program *symbols* and *objects* that is not very helpful.

A variable declared by the `var` keyword is reassignable whereas one declared with the `val` keyword is not.

A string is an immutable object type, once created it cannot be changed.

Whether a variable is *reassignable* and whether the object it points to is *immutable* are two different things.

Here's an example:

```
class Person(var name: String)

val fred = Person("Fred")

fred.name = "Barry" // fred is not immutable

fred = Person("Barry") // ERROR Val cannot be reassigned
```

So to use mutable in the way the documentation does, just because a *symbol* is declared a `val` does not make the *object* it points to immutable.

Comment: Yes, but is mutable and reassignable same?

Comment: Agreed that both are reassignable. But it doesn't mean mutable = reassignable. That's​ what I want to clarify

Comment: @FrankWilson Excellent example!

Comment: @RBK No mutable and reassignable are not the same. Mutable refers to the value - the data - that the variable points to. Reassignable refers whether you can point a variable to different data (a different value).

Comment: Additionally the braces after the class definition could be removed

Comment: @1blustone I've implemented your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What's the contradiction? A string is read-only. Just as Java, you cannot set `a[i] = 'x'`, any string replacement methods return new strings, etc. Therefore, not mutable. This point is made to clarify the functionality of a `var` String type

The difference between var and val can be associated with a `final` variable in Java. You can make a `final String` constant, or you can have a regular `String` object

Comment: Agreed that val and var is relate to java's final... But is a String declared with var mutable or immutable?

Comment: It's always immutable, as I explained and the documentation says... What exactly do you expect to do if a string was mutable?

Answer (score 3):

An [excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600058/1820644) by @Frank. It makes me more clear, what the documentation said.

The first part of the documentation says:

> Classes in Kotlin can have properties. **These can be declared as
>   mutable, using the var keyword** or read-only using the val keyword.

Now, the second part says:

> Strings are represented by the type String. **Strings are immutable.**

These both are true in my opinion.

Based on the Frank's example, let's take another example.

```
data class User(var name: String, var email:String)

var user1 = User("Foo","foo@bar.com")  
// user1 is mutable and object properties as well

val user2 = User("Bar","bar@foo.com")
// user2 is immutable but object's properties are mutable
```

Now, consider property **`user1`**. It is mutable as it is declared with keyword `var`. And also the User object assign to it.

But the `user2` property is immutable. You can not change the assigned object to it. But the Object itself has mutable properties. So the properties can be changes by `user2.name = "Foo"`.

Now changing the example a bit and making user properties immutable.

```
data class User(val name: String, val email:String)

var user1 = User("Foo","foo@bar.com")  
// user1 is mutable and object properties are not

val user2 = User("Bar","bar@foo.com")
// user2 is immutable and object's properties are also immutable
```

Here, User's properties are immutable. So, `user1` is mutable, you can assign another object to it. But the properties are immutable. So  `user1 = User("New Foo","newfoo@bar.com")` will work. But after assigning an object User, you can not change it's properties, as they are immutable.

Now, let's take an example with String type.

```
var str1 = "Bar"
// Here str1 (property) is mutable. So you can assign a different string to it. 
// But you can not modify the String object directly.
str1 = "Foo"  // This will work
str1[0] = 'B' // This will NOT work as The string object assigned to str1 is immutable

val str2 = "Foo"
// Here both str2 and the assigned object are immutable. (Just like Java final)
```

And as the Frank said,

> just because a symbol is declared a val does not make the object it points to immutable.

**My final cents:**

> String object is immutable, as it can not be changed. But that
>   immutable String object can be assigned to a mutable **property**, which
>   can be re-assigned with the different String Object. That is what
>   `var` keyword does. Making the property mutable. But the object it
>   points to can be mutable or immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find it easier to think about the difference between `val` and `var` in terms of Java. `val` would correspond to a variable with the `final` modifier, which means it can only be assigned once and `var` is just with that modifier absent and therefore reassignable.

The object themselves can still be either mutable or immutable. Mutability here refers to the variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin/Java an object's behaviour does *not* depend on the kind of reference you use to access it. Everything is (potentially) in the heap, so any property is just a reference (a.k.a. link) to the object.

```
val str = "Hello"
val a = str
var b = str
```

In the snippet above there is only one immutable string `str`, and both `a` and `b` reference it. You can't change the string, no matter what reference you use, mutable or immutable. But you can change the mutable reference itself to point to another (immutable) string:

```
b = "World"
```